# can't show contextmenu

Tags: android, sqlite, contextmenu

This is my application and you can see that I make a list of data ,have 2 list 
each list contain 2 line and 1 imagebutton and I want to make a ContextMenu ( whan I press on each list it will show a ContextMenu)

I have coded about onCreateContextMenu like this...

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            menu.add(0, EDIT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_edit);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case EDIT_ID:{
            Cursor cc = cursor;
            Intent edit_Im_Sens = new Intent(Im_SensShow.this,Im_SensEdit.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("THIMSENSID", thim_sens_id);
            bundle.putLong("IMSENSID", cc.getLong(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_IM_SENS_ID)));
            bundle.putLong("LANGSID", cc.getLong(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_LANGS_ID)));
            bundle.putString("IMSENS",cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_IM_SENS)));
            bundle.putString("READING",cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_READING)));
            edit_Im_Sens.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(edit_Im_Sens,1);
            //return true;
            break;
            }
```

but it doesn't work ,it doesn't show a ContextMenu 
please help....

Answer (score 0):

did you register the list view for context menu ?

registerForContextMenu(your_list)

```
// get the list view
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

// set adapter before registering the context menu
list.setAdapter(adapter);

// register it for the context menu
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

http://www.mikeplate.com/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/

Comment: No no ,2 lines that I've mented is data in list like this photo   
http://plixi.com/p/75290578#

you can see that each link have 2 line and 1 imagebutton  
so how can I gathering 2 line and 1 imagebutton to be 1 item?

Comment: ok, in the tutorial in the link it explains the part with the registerForContextMenu(list) function, changed it my answer.

Comment: sorry again I can't do it In my xml file I have main.xml and row.xml
in main.xml I 've ListView  like this
<ListView 
   android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
      android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

and in row.xml I have 
<TextView >
<TextView >
<ImageButton>
and I can get R.id.list T^T pls help me again

Comment: just a guess, make sure you have set the adapter before registering the context menu.

Comment: at the first time in main.xml I type android:id="@android:id/list"
and then I change it to android:id="@+id/list" for I can call it in"R.id.list" but even if I didn't register it for the context menu
my list doesn't show what should I do?

Comment: Have a look at this toturial, its not exactly like your problem but has to textviews, you can just adopt it and add your immage button. [link]( http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

Comment: thank you very much for your help ^^ but it still doesn't work T T

Comment: So your problem number 1 is that the list view does not display what it should ? right? Its not easy to figure out whats wrong this way, please show a screenshot, log outputs or even the source of the project, unless you are allowed to, but without more detail i can only point out examples which work.

Comment: ok,Tosa would you please give me your email ? (you can send your email to my email: zound617@gmail.com ) or if you feel uncomfortable it's ok to post my src code here ^^